# Bitmap 24 to 32 and back

Tags: c++

This may be a long post but I really need to know how to Convert between 24 and 32 bit bitmaps. For the sake of the length of this post, I removed the PNG part of my question.

Here goes:

I have a struct like the one below that holds all pixel information:

```
typedef union RGB
{
    uint32_t Color;
    struct
    {
        unsigned char B, G, R, A;
    } RGBA;
} *PRGB;

std::vector<RGB> Pixels;   //Holds all pixels.
```

All of the bitmap writing works except when going from 24 to 32 or vice-versa. I don't know what I'm doing wrong or why 24-32 conversions don't work. My bitmap reading and writing code is as follows:

```
Bitmap(const void* Pointer, int Width, int Height, uint32_t BitsPerPixel) //Constructor initialization here...
{
    Pixels.clear();
    if (Pointer == nullptr) {throw std::logic_error("Null Pointer Exception. Pointer is NULL.");}
    if (Width < 1 || Height < 1) {throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid Arguments. Width and Height cannot equal 0.");}
    std::memset(&Info, 0, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
    size = ((width * BitsPerPixel + 31) / 32) * 4 * height;

    Info.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    Info.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
    Info.bmiHeader.biHeight = height;
    Info.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    Info.bmiHeader.biBitCount = BitsPerPixel;
    Info.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    Info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = size;
    bFileHeader.bfType = 0x4D42;
    bFileHeader.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(Info.bmiHeader);
    bFileHeader.bfSize = bFileHeader.bfOffBits + size;

    const unsigned char* BuffPos = static_cast<const unsigned char*>(Pointer);
    height = (height < 0 ? -height : height);
    Pixels.resize(width * height);

    for (int I = 0; I < height; I++)
    {
        for (int J = 0; J < width; J++)
        {
            Pixels[(height - 1 - I) * width + J].RGBA.B = *(BuffPos++);
            Pixels[(height - 1 - I) * width + J].RGBA.G = *(BuffPos++);
            Pixels[(height - 1 - I) * width + J].RGBA.R = *(BuffPos++);
            Pixels[(height - 1 - I) * width + J].RGBA.A = (Info.bmiHeader.biBitCount > 24 ? *(BuffPos++) : 0);
        }
        if(Info.bmiHeader.biBitCount == 24)
            BuffPos += width % 4;
    }
}

bool SaveBitmap(const char* FilePath)
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> ImageData(size);
    unsigned char* BuffPos = ImageData.data();

    for (int I = 0; I < height; ++I)
    {
        for (int J = 0; J < width; ++J)
        {
            *(BuffPos++) = Pixels[(height - 1 - I) * width + J].RGBA.B;
            *(BuffPos++) = Pixels[(height - 1 - I) * width + J].RGBA.G;
            *(BuffPos++) = Pixels[(height - 1 - I) * width + J].RGBA.R;

            if (Info.bmiHeader.biBitCount > 24)
                *(BuffPos++) = Pixels[(height - 1 - I) * width + J].RGBA.A;
        }
        if(Info.bmiHeader.biBitCount == 24)
            BuffPos += width % 4;
    }

    std::fstream hFile(FilePath, std::fstream::out | std::ofstream::binary);
    if (!hFile.is_open()) return false;

    hFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&bFileHeader), sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
    hFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&Info.bmiHeader), sizeof (BITMAPINFOHEADER));
    hFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&ImageData[0]), Size());
    hFile.close();

    return true;
}
```

Any idea what the two problems could be? I want it so that if I called Bitmap(24BmpBuff, W, H, 32);  It'll save as 32. If I do  Bitmap(32BmpBuff, W, H, 24) it'll save as 24 bit. I just can't see it so I'm hoping one of you will.

I also tried making helper functions:

Convert From 24 bit to 32 bit.

```
void T24To32(std::vector<RGB> &Input, std::vector<RGB> &Output, int Width, int Height)
{
    Output.resize(Input.size());
    for (int I = 0; I < Height; ++I)
    {
        for (int J = 0; J < Width; ++J)
        {
            Output[J].RGBA.B = Input[J].RGBA.B;
            Output[J].RGBA.G = Input[J].RGBA.G;
            Output[J].RGBA.R = Input[J].RGBA.R;
            Output[J].RGBA.A = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Take the unsigned char* of pixels and store them upside down within the struct.

```
void Pack(int width, int height, int BPP, unsigned char* Input, std::vector<RGB> &Pixels)
{
    unsigned char* BuffPos = Input;
    height = (height < 0 ? -height : height);
    Pixels.resize(width * height);

    for (int I = 0; I < height; I++)
    {
        for (int J = 0; J < width; J++)
        {
            Pixels[(height - 1 - I) * width + J].RGBA.B = *(BuffPos++);
            Pixels[(height - 1 - I) * width + J].RGBA.G = *(BuffPos++);
            Pixels[(height - 1 - I) * width + J].RGBA.R = *(BuffPos++);
            Pixels[(height - 1 - I) * width + J].RGBA.A = (BPP > 24 ? *(BuffPos++) : 0);
        }
        if(BPP == 24)
            BuffPos += width % 4;
    }
}
```

Take the struct of pixels and store them upright in the unsigned char*.

```
void Unpack(int width, int height, int BPP, std::vector<RGB> Pixels, unsigned char* &Output)
{
    unsigned char* BuffPos = Output;

    for (int I = 0; I < height; ++I)
    {
        for (int J = 0; J < width; ++J)
        {
            *(BuffPos++) = Pixels[(height - 1 - I) * width + J].RGBA.B;
            *(BuffPos++) = Pixels[(height - 1 - I) * width + J].RGBA.G;
            *(BuffPos++) = Pixels[(height - 1 - I) * width + J].RGBA.R;

            if (BPP > 24)
                *(BuffPos++) = Pixels[(height - 1 - I) * width + J].RGBA.A;
        }
        if(BPP == 24)
            BuffPos += width % 4;
    }
}
```

I use all of the above like so.. Input image(32 bit): [image]

Code:

```
void Bitmap32ToBitmap24(int Width, int Height)
{
    Bitmap Image("C:/Images/Bitmap32.bmp");
    std::vector<unsigned char> Pixels(((Width * 32 + 31) / 32) * 4 * Height);   //Array large enough to hold 32 bit bmp.
    unsigned char* BuffPos = Pixels.data();

    Unpack(Width, Height, 32, Image.Get(), BuffPos);                            //Fill the array of unsigned char with image pixels being upright

    Bitmap BMP(Pixels.data(), Width, Height, 24);                               //Convert image to 24 bit bmp and save it.
    BMP.Save("C:/Images/Output/Bitmap32ToBitmap24.png");
}
```

Output image (24 bit): [image]
24 to 32 results in:
[image]

Comment: I've only glanced briefly at the code, but when converting 24->32 bit, you probably want to set the alpha to 255 and not 0, or you'll get a transparent image.

Comment: Which function produces wrong result, and with what arguments? What is that result? What is the desired result?

Comment: Added that info to the first post.

Comment: You are doing `Unpack` to create a 32-bit pixmap, and reading it as if it were a 24-bit pixmap. `BPP` in `Unpack` is the *output* image format, and `BitsPerPixel` in `Bitmap` is the *input* image format. They ought to be the same. The `width % 4` in the padding calculations is still a bug, solve it after you fix this one.

Comment: Hello sir, I solved it: http://pastebin.com/ARJrYqYY

That's the full code in case you want to see it. All I had to do was set the Info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage to the correct value. If it's incorrect, the bitmap gets fuzzy like show in the question post. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all your code snippets

```
if(Info.bmiHeader.biBitCount == 24)
        BuffPos += width % 4;
```

or

```
if(BPP == 24)
        BuffPos += width % 4;
```

occur. I assume this should add the padding value to each line. But it isn't the padding, it is the number of pixels per line %4.

The correct adding value is `(4 - ((width * 3) % 4)) % 4`. The width*3 is the number of bytes in that line. The `%4` calculates the number of bytes which are to many for a 4 byte padding, but to fill up to the next higher limes we need `4`-this value. This again is 4 if no padding offset is needed -> `%4` to avoid that.

A faster way to compute the same value is `(-width * 3) & 3`. See [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_padding#Computing_padding).

Comment: Hmm still doesn't pad. The result is the exact same :S

Comment: Sorry, I can't find anything else. All indices... are correct. Seeing the result it is definitly a problem with the line length in bytes. Do you set your Width and Height parameter correct?

Comment: I marked your answer as solved because this was a good answer :) I ended up changing my code to what you mentioned and it was padding correctly. Turns out the mistake was the Info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage. Thanks for the help. You prevented my future problems :D

Just in case you want to see the code: http://pastebin.com/ARJrYqYY